# Breaking out of php, but retain extraction results

Tags: php, html, mysql, break, extract

basically I am writing some some code that extracts data from a database about users and then displays it via php/html. I have a large amount of html that displays this data, and I think I should break out of PHP rather than escape everything such like `style=\"foo\"`

However, if I do this, the php inline with html then cannot return the variable pulled from the database. For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT u.name, u.surname FROM users AS u, bookings AS b WHERE u.ID = '".$bookings['booker_ID']."';";
$result=mysql_query(sql)

if ($r=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    extract($r);
}

<table class="table">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:300px">
            Host:
        </td>
        <td>
            <a>
            <?$name?> <?$surname?>
            </a>
........
```

Does not work, however, this does:

```
$sql = "SELECT u.name, u.surname FROM users AS u, bookings AS b WHERE u.ID='".$bookings['booker_ID']."';";
$result=mysql_query(sql)

if ($r=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    extract($r);
}

echo "<table class=\"table\">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style=\"width:300px\">
        Host:
        </td>
        <td>
            <a>
            ".$name" ".$surname."
            </a>
        ......
```

There is much more html involved in this, and it looks ugly/hard to read and is annoying to escape everything, is there a better way to do this/break out of php but retain the variables associated with the extraction of the results of the mysql query?

Thanks all!

Comment: You want to hear about templating - check Twig or Smarty or Mustache or whatever else.

Comment: @moonwave99 PHP is a perfect template system itself

Answer (score 1):

You can move in and out of PHP as often as you like.  From your example:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT u.name, u.surname FROM users AS u, bookings AS b WHERE u.ID = '".$bookings['booker_ID']."';";
$result=mysql_query(sql)


...

if ($r=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
extract($r);
}

?>

<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width:300px">
Host:
</td>
<td>
<a>
<?php echo $name ?> <?php echo $surname ?>
</a>
```

If you have control over your `php.ini` file, you can also turn on short tags and use the following:

```
<?= $name ." ". $surname ?>
```

Comment: Derp. wasnt using echo... so tired! appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<?=` for evaluate:

```
$sql = "SELECT u.name, u.surname FROM users AS u, bookings AS b WHERE u.ID = '".$bookings['booker_ID']."';";
$result=mysql_query(sql)

if ($r=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    extract($r);
}

<table class="table">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:300px">
            Host:
        </td>
        <td>
            <a>
            <?= $name ?> <?= $surname?>
            </a>
........
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already breaking out of your double quotes to evaluate your variables

```
<a>".$name" ".$surname."</a>
```

So why don't you use single quotes to `echo` out your content?

```
echo '<table class="table">...'.$name.'...';
```

You will not have to escape the double quotes but will the singles. The perk of using double quotes is that it will evaluate the PHP statements without needing to exit the quotes.

```
echo "...<a>$name $surname</a>..."
```

Your other option is to break out of PHP and then `echo` the variables as you need them

```
?>
<table class="table">
...
<?php echo $name; ?>
...
```

Take note that `<?=` is the Short Tag for `<?php echo`. This is a setting in the php.ini and may not be available for all servers. Also, you may look into [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax.

Comment: My server is set up for short tags so thats okay, I know people say not to use but bad habits and all that. Yeha im just overtired and missed my echo out in my non working code, thats why, feel a bit foolish!